# MariaDB/Mysql SELECT on CASE Statement inside CAST causes an error

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, mariadb-10.3

I'm working with a frustrating set of data that contains null, 0, 1, and 2 values for the 'active' column in my users table.

Why does this work:

```
SELECT u.id                                            AS LegacyContactKey,
       u.first_name                                    AS FirstName,
       u.last_name                                     AS LastName,
       c.company_name                                  AS CompanyName,
       u.email                                         AS EmailAddress,
       (CASE WHEN u.active = 1 THEN 1 WHEN u.active = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as IsMember
FROM tb_users AS u
    INNER JOIN tb_company AS c ON u.company_id = c.company_id
```

But not this?

```
SELECT u.id                                            AS LegacyContactKey,
       u.first_name                                    AS FirstName,
       u.last_name                                     AS LastName,
       c.company_name                                  AS CompanyName,
       u.email                                         AS EmailAddress,
       CAST((CASE WHEN u.active = 1 THEN 1 WHEN u.active = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BOOLEAN) as IsMember
FROM tb_users AS u
    INNER JOIN tb_company AS c ON u.company_id = c.company_id
```

I want to cast one of my query results as a boolean so it returns true or false but when I add CAST() I get an error  (near BOOLEAN)

Running MariaDB 10.3

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `cast()` supports boolean.  But the simplest method is really:

```
   (u.active IN (1, 2)) as IsMember
```

You can just use a boolean expression and assign a column alias to it.

EDIT:

If `NULL` is an issue, just include it in the expression:

```
   (u.active IN (1, 2) AND u.active IS NOT NULL) as IsMember
```

Comment: This would give you ```NULL``` if ```u.active``` is already ```NULL```. Use ```(CASE WHEN u.active IN (1, 2) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END)``` or ```COALESCE(u.active IN (1, 2), FALSE)``` instead.

Comment: This works but does not return "true" or "false".  I was hoping to return true or false in the query since I'm preparing this for a request where 0,1 doesn't work.  Not a big deal I suppose since I can still make the conversion outside the query.

Comment: @ChrisStage . . . You can convert to a string, if you want a string value.